# How to use CNN-LSTMs to classify image sequences for multiple bounding boxes in a video stream?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification, lstm

I am working on a pytorch project, where I’m using a webcam video stream. An object detector is used to find objects within the frame and each box is given an id by a tracker. Then, I want to analyse each bounding box with a CNN-LSTM and classify it (binary classification) based on the previous frame sequence of that box (for the last 5 frames). I want the program to run a close to real-time as possible.
Currently I am stuck with the CNN-LSTM part of my problem - the detector and tracker are working quite well already.
I am a little bit clueless on how to approach this task. Here are the questions I have:

**1)** How does inferencing work in this case? Do I have to save np arrays for each bounding box containing the last 5 frames, then add the current frame and delete the oldest one? Then use the model for each bounding box that is in the current frame. This way sounds very slow and inefficient. Is there a faster or easier way?

**2)** Do you have any tipps for creating the dataset? I have a couple of videos with bounding boxes and labels. Should I loop through the videos and save save each frame sequence for each bounding box in a new folder, together with a csv that contains the label? I have never worked with an CNN-LSTM, so I don’t know how to load the data for training.

**3)** Would it be possible to use the extracted features of the CNN in parallel? As mentioned above, The extracted features should be used by the LSTM for a binary classification problem. The classification is only needed for the current frame. I would like to use an additional classifier (8 classes) based on the extracted CNN features, also only for the current frame. For this classifier, the LSTM is not needed.

Since my explaining propably is very confusing, the following image hopefully helps with understanding what I want to build:

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcVgq.png)

This is the architecture I want to use. Is this possible using Pytorch? So far, I only worked with CNNs and LSTM seperately. Any help is apprechiated :)

Comment: If you don't need to train the detector then I think saving the box as numerical for every frame is a good idea. Loading 4-5 float parameters per frame won't hurt the ram no matter how long the video is.

Comment: Then you just need to load the boxes in a dict and use frame count (or file name if you save all frames to images) to match the box.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply :) what exactly do you mean by float parameter? Do you mean compressing the information of the pixels within the bounding box using  an encoder? Would that not mean that i have to use a decoder for each previous frame for each box when inferencing? Tme that sounds pretty slow, but i have not tried it yet.

Comment: No, just save the `(x1, y1, x2, y2, class)` in a file (maybe JSON). Then crop the images when you actually need them.